# What would cause repeated failure of ignition coils?

Tags: ignition, ignition-coil

I have a Nissan 2008 Rogue, which is fired by ignition coil.  I've been experiencing repeated singular ignition coil failures every 1-2 months now for the past 6 months.  I'm on my 6th failure, never the same one, always different.  Does anyone have any troubleshooting steps that could help me here?

Comment: Are you replacing them with oem?

Comment: I had a maxima with bad ground that fried a couple coils and later fried computer.

Comment: The first replacement set was OEM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will post what I found here and let others add on as they desired.  A helpful Youtube video:[Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YKntQheRHHw).  His statement regarding high resistance in the secondary, made me think to pull the spark plugs and check the gaps.  When I pulled the plug, I could tell right away the plug gaps were wrong (that's how bad they were .1" instead of .04").  I'm pretty disappointed since it has barely been 30K miles on these plugs, but I think the plugs were the culprit.

Comment: That's quite a difference in spark plug gap.  If they were installed by a workshop I'd be perusing them for the cost of at least some of the ignition coils.

Comment: Agreed. However, I replaced the plugs. To be clear the plugs were not the same gap as when they were installed.  It looked like the iridium stud had worn down to a nub.

Comment: I'd double check with the manufacturer of the car and the manufacturer of the plugs that they were definitely the correct part number for your vehicle.

Comment: That's a great suggestion.  I picked them straight off of AutoZone, but with my WRX, I ended up getting plugs that looked nothing looked the orginals.  Needless to say, I returned those and went elsewhere.  So, perhaps they got these wrong too.